# Base Directory - Illegal characters in path

Tags: c#, appdomain

I'm having problems with a line where the base directory (the location of the .exe itself) is found, and a line from a text file within is read.

It's throwing up the 'illegal characters in path' error for this line in the code:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\Parameters.txt"));
```

It may be as a result of me formatting the arguments  of `StreamReader()` wrong, (probably `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`) but I can't be sure as there's not much other material about appdomain out there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well you cant do `"\Parameters.txt"`. Do `"\\Parameters.txt"` or `"/Parameters.txt"`

Comment: ^ i have tried that also. It still throws the same error.

Comment: I have spotted the issue now, see my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overload for the `StreamReader` constructor that takes a `string` argument is a filename, not content.

Use `StringReader` instead, or remove `File.ReadAllText`.

Comment: Thank you. Perfect answer. I would vote up this answer, but i don't have enough rep yet.

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Parameters.txt");
```

There are other overload of this function, e.g.

```
Combine(String[])           //Combines an array of strings into a path.
Combine(String, String)     //Combines two strings into a path.
Combine(String, String, String)             //Combines three strings into a path.
Combine(String, String, String, String)     //Combines four strings into a path.
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Remove `'\'` from your path...

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Parameters.txt"));
```

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Parameters.txt"` - > This Returns the Correct path like below

**Path :** `\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Sample\Sample\bin\Release\Parameters.txt`

So no need of '\' in that path